# Nodejs server disconnecting after idle for too long (ECONNRESET)

Tags: database, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Good day,
I have the following issue:
my node.js server which is running node-postgres to communicate with a database gives the error read ECONNRESET when a client asks for it to query the database.

HOWEVER, this only happens when the server, and by extension the connection, is idle for too long (1 hour I believe,not sure though).

Is there a way to avoid this? My solution does require the connection to the database to stay permanently up as the clients' messages can be sparse but still very important.

EDIT: I'm using the socket.io and node-postgres modules

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom code in a language which has a stable Postgres driver (Java?). Obtain a connection and sleep for 10, 20, 30, 60, 90, 120 minutes in progression and check driver connectivity with a sql query.

If the same behavior is observed for a long idle connection, then it's not a nodejs problem. The problem is either the Postgres DB config which closes an idle connection or a firewall which deletes connections to maintain efficient operation